# I have an audio file that's supposed to be video

Tags: video

So, I have an audio file that's a video but unencoded and as an audio file. I recorded it in Audacity, and I need to view it as a video. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In order to view an audio file as a video, you would need to combine the audio with a visual element, such as a still image or a series of images. One way to do this is to use a video editing software, such as Adobe Premiere Pro or Final Cut Pro, to import the audio file and combine it with visual elements to create a video file. Another option would be to use a software specifically designed for creating videos from audio files.